# Unable to deactivate / delete Process Builder version - insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: process-builder, livechattranscript

I have a ProcessBuilder in the org constructed in 2017 that referenced `LiveChatTranscript` as the target object.

When I try and deactivate/delete the only version of this process, I get

```
insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
```

When I look at the Process in the UX, it looks like this:

[image]

How do I deactivate/delete this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the org stopped licensing `Live Agent` in 2019.  As such, the various objects associated with a Live Agent feature license such as `LiveChatTranscript` are no longer visible to the org.

You would think that Salesforce would invalidate the ProcessBuilders that referenced such objects and allow for their deactivation/deletion. But, apparently not.

Solution was to contact both Support and our account rep and:

- Get a courtesy license for 1 month for `LiveAgent`.
- Once this was done, the Process Builder `miraculously` repopulated and it could be deactivated/deleted.
- If you have active sandboxes, you'll need to do `Setup | Company | Match Production Licenses` to propagate your courtesy license into your staging and CI orgs (assuming they aren't being refreshed from PROD)